# Instrument an Android APK

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

How to instrument an Android APK when the source code is not available?

I'm building a testing tool that uses an APK as input and I need to instrument the APK. Basically, I want to instrument all the occurrence of a specific function (e.g. foo) and change the values of the arguments. For example, if the APK uses the function:

```
foo("x")
```

The instrumentation has to change the argument

```
foo(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this project : https://github.com/paul-irolla/androcoverage... It uses EMMA to automatically instrument applications and generate code coverage reports..

one suggestion though.. convert the APK to JAR before using EMMA Tool.....

P.S : Do take backup of your APK file before converting it to a JAR.